# Unix switch user using password from file

Tags: unix

How can I switch user using su command and adding password from file ?

I want to make a script which will automatically switch the user, having the user and the password ,without manually typing the password.

Note: I don't have super user rights.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to another stack exchange site like "Unix & Linux".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!